# How do I selectively share data with clients, so that they only see their own data, and not of their competitors?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data like this in my Excel 2013 workbook

**Table 1:**

```
       Col A         Col B          Col B
1      Client 1      .....          123
2      Client 1      .....          456
3      Client 1      .....          99
4      Client 2      .....          324
5      Client 2      .....          989
6      Client 3      .....          234
7      Client 3      .....          23
```

I am using this Table 1 for a client specific report elsewhere in the excel. e.g.

**Client Report: Client 1**

```
       Col A         Col B          Col C          Col D
1      Client 1      123            456            99
```

The cell A1 in the report is a data validation dropdown containing the names of the Clients. I can change that dropdown to Client 2

**Client Report: Client 2**

```
       Col A         Col B          Col C          Col D
1      Client 2      324            989
```

***What I want to be able to do is send out one file to all clients, which contains the Client Report, but each Client should only be able to see their own data.*** As a bonus, each client should also not be able to see which other clients are on the list (i.e. in the file that Client 1 receives, he/she should not have access to the numbers of Client 2 and Client 3, and as a bonus, should not even see the names Client 2 and Client 3)

I have an option of creating these files manually, for each client. I am looking for a way to hide data in a file depending on which Client it is for, and thus sending out the same file to multiple clients (I have ~30 clients, so the manual process will be error prone and a pain). I don't want to create 30 separate files or sheets if I can help it. The ideal way would be to build a 'master' option, which gives me access to all data, but not to the client who I send this out to. However, ***data confidentiality is super critical***, and if password protection in Excel Workbooks is questionable, then I would not want this option, and I will go back to manual :)

Also, even though I am only looking for vanilla Excel solutions (I can't rely on my clients to have addons installed or install one just for the sake of this), if you do know of interesting ways to address this kind of a problem with addons, please do comment/answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I understand. I believe I still do have a right to ask the question, and have it answered as 'No' without the downvote/judgement.

Comment: Write a macro to spit out 30 workbooks - a simple search would tell you excel password protection can be broken in seconds

Comment: Thank you. You can add that as an answer as well, I will accept it if there is no other answer.

Comment: I agree with @StevenMartin, You should have a look at creating an MS Access Database and then you can use Macros in Access to Export the Specific Client data, when needed, to Excel. IF you do a quick Google Search for Excel vs Access you can see the benefits

Comment: You do indeed have a right to ask questions ... but with every right comes a responsibility. You also have the responsibility not to ask how to break the law... and causing financial loss by breach of confidentiality is illegal. Respondents here not only can but should downvote or judge. If they give you the code to answer your question they may very well be as exposed to a civil action as you would be. Follow @StevenMartin's advice and run a macro to create 30 workbooks. And if my advice is worth anything, then make sure your employer can never link this post to you.

Comment: a) "to ask how to break the law" - I am not asking how to break the law, I am asking if this can be done reliably, without data breach. I am sure my employer will have no problems with this or any question, because data breach is exactly what I want to avoid as well. 
b) "Follow @StevenMartin's advice" - It's what I am doing already, and I indicated it to him as well, that I would accept that as an answer. I am not comfortable with the tone of his first comment. It may not be painfully obvious to me that this cannot be done, as it is to you, but that is no reason to be rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steven Martain said, there is NO SECURITY in Excel.  You can password-protect your Workbook, but the password can be broken in no time at all.  Instead split your file into several separate files.  Please see this link for an idea of how to do this.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006.htm

Then, simply email the different files to different recipients/clients/people.  See this link for an idea of how to do that.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it without coding/VB. However, you can use InstaRow ( check [here](http://dataforsharing.com)). Which is perfect tool for this problem. You can signup with email id ( and your clients). They will see exactly their portion. 
They can even change data easily.

Answer (score -2):

Posting @StevenMartin 's answer from the comments above, as it seems to the way to go about it

"Write a macro to spit out 30 workbooks - a simple search would tell you excel password protection can be broken in seconds"